# Resolving IDL Warning MIDL2471: Some attributes and/or data types in the idl can not be represented in the type library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, compiler-warnings, idl

A project I'm working on started producing the following warning:

> Warning MIDL2471: Some attributes and/or data types in the idl and/or
>   included/imported idl files can not be represented in the type
>   library: : unique [ Parameter 'eventData' of Procedure 'Event' (
>   Dispinterface '_Events' ) ]

I've tried to research this, however, it appears to be a very obscure warning, so I'm hoping someone has seen or experienced and solved this before. I've been cranking on resolving this warning for about a full day now without progress.  A sample of the bit of code producing the warning, from "Communicator.idl", is:

```
dispinterface _Events
{
    properties:
    methods:
    [id(1)] void ConnectStatusChange([in]long lStatus, [in]long lLastError);
    [id(2)] void Event([in]long lEvent, [in, unique]SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) * eventData);
    [id(3)] void CriticalEvent([in]long lEvent,  [in, unique]SAFEARRAY(unsigned char) * critEventData, [in] long lEventID);
    [id(4)] void Log([in]BSTR bstrMessage, DWORD dwMessageType);
};
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I never did solve this problem. Rather, we ended up refactoring it away unintentionally and never knew for sure what was causing this. However, because I never received any answers and because there was next to nothing online about this, I'm heavily inclined it was something environmental with my VS install, so that I never knew what was wrong probably isn't likely to matter much at this point.